# How to import Python methods of existing classes selectively?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following example that imports additional Pandas methods from the `pyjanitor` package.

```py
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column One': [1, 2, 3],
    'Column-Two': [4, 5, 6],
    'Column@Three': [7, 8, 9],
})

df_cleaned = df.clean_names()
print(df_cleaned)
#>    column_one  column_two  column@three
#> 0           1           4             7
#> 1           2           5             8
#> 2           3           6             9
```

Is there a way to **import methods** from Python packages, modules, or other sources more **transparently**/**explicitly** (to know which method came from which package) and/or **selectively** (to import only the methods of interest, e.g., only `.clean_names()` but not the remaining ones)?

Note: I do not want to import a method as a function and use it as a function. I would like to control what methods are imported.

Comment: No, it's not possible to import methods selectively.

Comment: Methods don't come from a package, they're part of the class.

Answer (score 5):

pyjanitor is **extremely** unusual. Adding methods to a class defined somewhere else is technically legal in Python, but almost no one does it. Most of the time, you can safely assume that any methods of a class come from the module that defines the class, or are inherited from parent classes.

It is not possible to selectively import only some of an object's methods. An object has the same methods no matter what code is looking at it. (It might suddenly grow more methods if a module like pyjanitor adds more, but if so, those new methods will be available to any code that accesses the object after that point.)

Comment: "Originally a port of the R package" of course

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, if you look at `pyjanitor` [source code](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/blob/936fa8b0c95e5dedd51e3d9044080d1ba5307c94/janitor/functions/clean_names.py#L12). You'll see that the `clean_names` has a decorator to register that method to the pandas dataframe. The only possible way I would see is if you forked `pyjanitor` edited the [register method](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pandas_flavor/blob/5b1ab54ab7e2810370ad683e1c46ea3ccf438cf9/pandas_flavor/register.py#L98) to do nothing and then import your version of it.